# Node.js readFile async callback UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to supply an async function to node.js's `fs.readFile` callback, but I am not too sure how to handle the errors thrown by the callback. Normally, with non-async callback, you would do:

```
// error is handled

fs.readFile('/file_does_not_exist.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err
  // do things here
})
```

And if a `readFile` error occurs, it is handled properly. But as soon as I use an async function as a callback:

```
// UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

fs.readFile('/file_does_not_exist.txt', 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err
  // await for things here
})
```

Then it throws `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when a `readFile` error occurs. How would you try to handle the `err` in this scenario? I have tried `try catch` in the body of the callback, but it doesn't work. The only other solution is to wrap the async function inside another function.

Comment: Why not handle it ... where you have the `if (err)`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use [`fs/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api)? (and yeah, agree with @trincot: re-throwing an error isn't "handling it")

Comment: @robertklep could you help me clarify what it means when you say handle it? I thought you are meant to throw the error. And `console.error()` gives me a similar result. I also tried `fs/promises`—now it doesn't give me `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when I simply `try catch` and `console.error(err)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expected that you get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error, because throwing an error isn't the same as handling it.

If your goal is to exit the process:

```
if (err) {
  process.exit(1);
}
```

If you want to continue running the program but somehow handle the error upstream, you'll end up mixing callbacks and promises, which typically leads to convoluted code.

Instead, I would suggest using [`fs/promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api), the Promise-based implementation of `fs`:

```
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');
… 
async function readFile() {
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile('/file_does_not_exist.txt', 'utf8');
    // process file data
  } catch(e) {
    console.error('caught error reading file', e);
    // here you can cleanly exit the process or re-throw `e` to properly handle it upstream
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.readFile('/file_does_not_exist.txt', 'utf8', async (err, data) => {
  //if (err) throw err
  /* replace it to */
  if (err) {
    //handle error here
  } else {
    // await for things here
  }
})
```